# Programmatically setting MAVEN_OPTS from groovy script

Tags: groovy

I am trying to write a build script in groovy and I want to ensure that the MAVEN_OPTS are set based on the build scripts configuration.

What I have is:

```
def process = ['export MAVEN_OPTS=\"-Xmx' + config.buildEnvironment.maxMemory + ' -XX:MaxPermSize=' + config.buildEnvironment.maxPermSize + '\"'].execute()
process.in.eachLine { line ->               
   println(line)                            
}
```

`config.buildEnvironment.maxMemory` resolves to *1024m* while `config.buildEnvironment.maxPermSize` resolves to *512m*

The output from this is:

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"": error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"": error=2, No such file or directory
    at MavenUtils.setMavenDefaultOpts(MavenUtils.groovy:23)
    at MavenUtils$setMavenDefaultOpts.call(Unknown Source)
    at build.run(build.groovy:19)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    ... 3 more
```

I'm using the String.execute() functionality a lot through my script to build maven projects, copy files etc, but this is the first time I have come across this type of error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not possible.

I will encapsulate this logic into a shell script and execute that instead, and that's how I will get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be not possible. However since, `export` is shell builtin you should run:

```
['sh', '-c', 'export', 'LOL=LOL'].execute().in.eachLine { println it }
```